# Update cairo text with a loop in PyGTK for countdown

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, cairo

I am trying to write some code to put a countdown over a live preview for a photobooth. I would like the previous number to disappear when the new number is generator but to troubleshoot I wrote the code so that they appear in a different position just so I can see what's happening. Unfortunately, only 2 numbers print "4" which I'm just printing as a test, then the first number in the actual loop which is "3" then nothing else prints. I don't know why 2 numbers would print and not the rest.

```py
countdown_timer = 4

count_area = gtk.DrawingArea()
count_area.set_app_paintable(True)
fixed.put(count_area, 20, 20)


def counter(widget, event, count, pos):
    count_area = widget.window.cairo_create()
    count_area.set_source_rgb(0.9, 0.5, 0.9)
    count_area.select_font_face("Purisa", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
    count_area.set_font_size(25)
    count_area.move_to(30, pos+90)
    count_area.show_text(count)
      
def start_counter(da):
    global countdown_timer
    countdown = countdown_timer
    fixed.connect("expose-event", counter, str(countdown), countdown*20)
    while countdown > 0:
        print "This is the start_counter function speaking:", countdown
        countdown -= 1
        fixed.connect("expose-event", counter, str(countdown), countdown*20)
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if countdown == 0:
            fixed.connect("expose-event", counter, "Smile!", countdown*20)
            break            

count_area.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my first post here. Also my test print statement in the loop prints as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the kind of sleep-loops that you do in start_counter() when you do UI programming. Also the idea of connecting to the expose-event multiple times is just wrong.

You could setup a GLib timer that calls a function that updates a countdown instance variable every second (see `glib.timeout_add_seconds()`) -- this makes the sleeping loop entirely unneeded. Then in the expose-event handler you read the countdown instance variable and draw what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't smart enough to figure how to use cairo for what I wanted, so I decided to just use a label instead. I kept the functions in the main loop of the program which I probably shouldn't have, but it seems to work. Instead of threading I used gobject.timeout_add

```py
#set the countdown time in seconds
countdown_timer = 4

def countdown_clicked(self, sender):
    global countdown_timer
    counter = countdown_timer
    while counter >= 0:
        gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, countdown_function, countdown_timer-counter)
        counter -= 1

def countdown_function(counter):
    if counter > 0:
        fixed.label.set_text(str(counter))
    else:
        fixed.label.set_text(" :)")
        self.photo_cb()
        
        
startB_image = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_YES, gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)
startB = gtk.Button()
startB.set_image(startB_image)
startB.set_tooltip_text("Start countdown")
startB.connect('clicked', countdown_clicked, None)                

fixed.label = gtk.Label("Z")     
fixed.label.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("sans 48"))
fixed.label.modify_text(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("#00FF00"))
#fixed.label.modify_font(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("#00FF00"))
fixed.add(fixed.label)  
fixed.show()
```

I couldn't get the label to change colors though. It stays black.

Comment: The GLib timeout is correct; `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` would queue the widget for redraw, at which point you could draw your new text. As for adjusting the font and colors, you don't want to use the `modify_***` functions of GtkWidget. Instead, to change the font, set the `attributes` field to a PangoAttrList that contains the styles that you want (and I think you'll need custom CSS for colors; see GtkStyleContext). I don't remember the full details right now, sorry.